# How to make one page real-time in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that is already fully built, the only thing I'd like to add is real-time rendering of one of my pages.
Suppose it is a page with all the pizzas. When pizza is added to the database, I'd like page to show it without refreshing.

I know you can do it with websockets, but is there any easier way? Could, eg, *AngularJS* help here (as I understand it refreshes the page contents as soon as model is changed)?

Comment: You need information from the server. While, sockets would probably be the way to go (you could use Pusher for help), there are also other techniques, like long-polling, etc.

Comment: @David, Pusher was a good advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could make a small service in Angular that asks the server like every 15 secons or so, to see if there are new pizzas added to the database. (Say the last time you took the pizzas from the server you had 15 of them returned. Now you send that number 15 back with the check request and compare it with the database)

If so, it will call the query method in the pizza Angular service to fetch the new pizzas.
If this is a small table with often changing info then I would also suggest to migrate this model into Redis instead. Asking info repeteadly from Redis is a lot cheaper than it is to ask like this from a database.

Comment: Read up on simple ajax requests to the server. Angular seems like too much of an investment for one page.

Comment: Might be. But in case @Jayden decides to develop the website further one day, then it would be a lot better solution to have the front-end done with Angular, following proper Angular development patterns. Helps with easier maintenance later on.